# Manipulate the volume of a constantly repeating audio in Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet, python-3.10

How can I manipulate the volume of the audio loaded via `pyglet.media.load`?

The reason is that I have to repeat a sound repeatedly (eg bullets), but if I use the Player, the sound is queued to be able to play it and plays it only once using `.play()` (eg `bullet = pyglet.media.load("bullet.wav", streaming=False) audioPlayer = pyglet.media.Player() audioPlayer.queue(bullet)` if the `audioPlayer.play()` command is used several times, for example from a key, it is executed only once and that's it)

If I don't use the Player, I can use the sound constantly, but at that point I can no longer manipulate the volume of the audio. (eg `bullet = pyglet.media.load("bullet.wav", streaming=False) bullet.play()`)

So how can I go about solving the problem? I don't have much experience using Pyglet audio, so I'm probably ignoring something I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The audio player is the correct approach as you can set volume on the player.

`audioPlayer.volume = 0.5`

Under the hood all the `media.play()` command does is create a `Player` instance, queue and play it. If you want to replay something, simply queue the source and play the player again. If you need audio overlaps, then you would create separate `Player` instances every time, like `media.play()` would.

Comment: So should I for example in loop or alternatively in an update function continue to queue the audio? Because it is not a music, but a sound effect that is automatically activated constantly (in my case it is the sound of the letters that appear in the dialogues). So every time a letter appears the sound plays and since it's al how fast, so how exactly should I do?

Comment: Are your sounds fast enough to play/stop everytime a letter appears? If so, you can just queue as many sounds as you want in sequence that match the length of your text. You can do this in the same function you are setting text, or you can create a loop. It's up to you, you can do it either way.